# Why do I Get an 'Implicit Coercion of Value; error when exporting a swc from Flash Pro CS6 into Flash Builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, import, flash-builder, swc

I create my symbol with a class name

[image]

I publish as an SWC, and in flash buildr it looks like this

[image]
[image]

I **import MyRect** and try and use it

```
var redRect:MyRect = new MyRect;
     addChild(redRect);
```

I get an error

**Implicit coercion of a value of type MyRect to an unrelated type DisplayObject....line 93 Flex Problem**

Comment: You can not add MovieClip (or Sprite) classes directly to most Flex components - try adding MyRect to a UIComponent instead.

Comment: it is an actionscript project

Comment: why do you have "Flex" in your error message then?

Comment: see latest screen was at the end in the 'type' box. But this is setup on FB 4.7 as an Actionscript project running on air.

Comment: When you open up your swc in the "Referenced Libraries" part of the Project Explorer, do you see a MyRect.abc Class listed there?

Comment: Your subject line is a bit confusing.  Is it safe to assume you are exporting using Flash Professional CS6? I tried modifying the subject line to be more clear.  Are you seeing a compile time error or a runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in how your declaring it. It might have to do with the object type. Try this:

```
var objects:Array;
objects = [0];
objects[0] = new MyRect();
addChild(objects[0]);
```

and see what happens.

Comment: Why would putting the component in an Array affect this?

Comment: I think Ronnie is trying to get around the typing error by using an essentialy untyped variable.

Comment: Which would remove the compile-time error, but the runtime-error would still exist. To Ronnie: You could get around this simply by doing `addChild( new Rect() as * )` instead of what you did. Regardless, this will only help compiler errors and will crash the app when it hits that line.